# $\lim\limits_ {n \to \infty} \left( \cos ^{2n} \left(\frac{k \pi}{3}\right)-\cos ^{2n}\left(\frac{k \pi}{5}\right)\right )=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

For how many values of $k=1,2,3,....200$ $$\lim\limits_ {n \to \infty} \left( \cos ^{2n} \left(\frac{k \pi}{3}\right)-\cos ^{2n}\left(\frac{k \pi}{5}\right)\right )=0$$

My Try:

Let $A=\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{3}\right)$ and $B=\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{5}\right)$

The limit approaches zero only if

$$A=B=1$$ OR

$$A=B=-1$$  OR

$$A=B=0$$

if $A=B=1$ or $A=B=-1$ $\implies$

$$\frac{k \pi}{3}=2m \pi$$ and

$$\frac{k \pi}{5}=2n \pi$$

OR

$$\frac{k \pi}{3}=(2m+1) \pi$$ and

$$\frac{k \pi}{5}=(2n+1) \pi$$

$\implies$ $k$ is a multiple of $15$  which are $13$ in number.

Finally if $A=B=0$ we have

$$\frac{k \pi}{3}=(2m+1) \frac{\pi}{2}$$ and

$$\frac{k \pi}{5}=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$ $\implies$

Any idea of how to find number of $k's$ in this case?

Comment: Or $A=1,B=-1$; or $A=-1,B=1$; or $k/3$ and $k/5$ are both not even integers.

Comment: That is not possible since $\frac{k}{3}=2m+1$ and $\frac{k}{5}=2n$ $\implies$ $10n=6m+3$

Comment: Your last case does not have solutions (the product of odd numbers will be an odd number and cannot be wholly divided by 2)

Comment: $A=B=0$ is not required. $|A|=|b|<1$ suffices.

Answer (score 1):

**A different approach.** It is worth mentioning that 
$$0\leq \cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)\leq1 \text{ and } 0\leq \cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\leq1$$
for $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$. As a result ($0\leq a \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0\leq a^n \leq 1, n\in \mathbb{N}$)
$$0\leq \cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)\leq1 \text{ and } 0\leq \cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\leq1$$
[It is also known](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bk%20%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%7Da%5Ek) (or can easily be shown) that 
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}a^n=0, 0\leq a<1 \tag{1}$$ 
As a result
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)−\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\right)=0 \tag{2}$$
is true when

1. $\color{red}{3 \nmid k \text{ and }5 \nmid k}$, because in this case $0\leq \cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)< 1 \text{ and } 0\leq \cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)< 1$. It results from $(1)$ and $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)−\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\right)=\\
   \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)\right)−\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\right)=\\
   0-0=0$$
2. $\color{red}{3 \mid k \text{ and } 5 \mid k \text{ or simply } 15 \mid k}$, because in this case $\cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)=1 \text{ and } \cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)=1$ and 
   $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)−\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\right)=\\
   \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)\right)−\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\cos^{2n}\left(\frac{k\pi}{5}\right)\right)=\\
   1-1=0$$

In all the other case, the limit is either $1$ or $-1$. Those "other cases" are $\color{red}{3 \mid k \text{ or } 5 \mid k \text{ but } 15 \nmid k}$ or playing with [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) $\left \lfloor \frac{200}{3} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{200}{5} \right \rfloor - 2\left \lfloor \frac{200}{15} \right \rfloor=80$ of cases when $(2)$ is not true. Or $200-80=120$ cases when $(2)$ is true.